# Limiting distribution of $\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^{n}|S_{k-1}|(X_k^2 - 1)$ where $X_k$ are i.i.d standard normal

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, convergence, central-limit-theorem

> Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of i.i.d $\mathcal N(0,1)$ random variables. Define $S_0=0$ and $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ for $n\geq 1$. Find the limiting distribution of $$\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^{n}|S_{k-1}|(X_k^2 - 1)$$

This problem is from a problem book on Probability Theory, in the chapter on the Central Limit Theorem.

Since $S_{k-1}$ and $X_k$ are independent, $E(|S_{k-1}|(X_k^2 - 1))=0$ and $$V(|S_{k-1}|(X_k^2 - 1)) = E(S_{k-1}^2(X_k^2 - 1)^2)=  E(S_{k-1}^2)E(X_k^2 - 1)^2) =2(k-1)$$

Note that the $|S_{k-1}|(X_k^2 - 1)$ are clearly not independent. The problem is from Shiryaev's *Problems in Probability*, which is itself based on the textbook from the same author. The textbook does not seem to cover the CLT for correlated variables. I don't know if there's a stationary, mixing sequence hiding somewhere...

I have run simulations to get a feel of the answer

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 20000 #summation index
m = 2000 #number of samples

X = np.random.normal(size=(m,n))
sums = np.cumsum(X, axis=1)
sums = np.delete(sums, -1, 1)
prods = np.delete(X**2-1, 0, 1)*np.abs(sums)
samples = 1/n*np.sum(prods, axis=1)

plt.hist(samples, bins=100, density=True)
x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))
plt.show()
```

Below is a histogram of $2000$ samples ($n=20.000$). It looks fairly normally distributed...

[image]

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I posted this because I've pondered the problem for some time and I'm stuck. It is probably far from trivial...

Comment: @MartijnWeterings $E(|S_{k-1}|(X_k^2 - 1)) = 0$, hence $V(|S_{k-1}|(X_k^2 - 1)) = E(S_{k-1}^2(X_k^2 - 1)^2)$

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Yes, I omitted the trivial equality $|x|^2=x^2$ for $x\in \mathbb R$...

Comment: The histogram in the simulation is a terrible match for the Normal distribution.  If you're not convinced, compute the kurtosis.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Yes, I made an embarassing omission in the code. I've updated it, as well as the histogram, which looks like a normal one. Do you have an idea of the exact value of the variance ?

Comment: @whuber As pointed out by Martijn Weterings, there was a mistake in my code, see the updated histogram.

Comment: For uncorrelated terms you would have roughly $\sigma^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_{k}^2 = \sum _{k=1}^n 2 k = n(n-1) \approx n^2 $ and the variance would be I guess 1. I get quite a similar result with a simulation.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings If the limiting distribution was $\mathcal N(0,1)$ the peak of the histogram should be $\sim 0.4$, but in my simulations I observe something close to $0.6$. Do you see something different ?

Comment: I will post it in an incomplete answer.

Comment: @GabrielRomon does your textbook say anything about q-Gaussians in a context of a generalization of the CLT?

Comment: The histogram is still noticeably non-Gaussian, nor would we expect it to be.

Comment: @whuber It might be [q-Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Gaussian_distribution).

Comment: @Martijn I am curious: what is the intuition that suggested this to you?

Comment: To be honest I do not know much about it. But there are several extensions of CLT using the q-Gaussian distribution and they relate to such correlated variables as in the question by the OP. (also the curve does fit nicely to simulated data, I will update that in the answer below)

Comment: Possibly you might model this as a random walk in 2D where steps are made according to $X_i \sim N (0,1)$ (a one dimensional random walk). And the $Y_i$ step is equal to $X_i^2-1$ but multiplied by the magnitude of the  current X position (as if there is some acceleration in the vertical direction). Then possibly it could be modelled (and solved) as some sort of diffusion process.

Comment: Or possibly with different coordinates.

Comment: Interresting to know might be that you could also use other terms than $X^2-1$, for instance when you use a Bernoulli distributed variable with values $\pm \sqrt{8} $ like $$\sum_{k=1}^n S_k B_k $$ then you get the same limiting distribution (at least simulations show me this). All of these type of equations can be relate to a PDE like: $$u_t = u_{xx} + 2 x u_{yy} $$ I believe you might solve that as some exponent of a polynomial.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Interesting ! I was thinking the other day that it might help to write $|S_{k-1}| = (2\cdot 1_{S_{k-1}\geq 0} -1)S_{k-1}$... Also, in simulations, do your samples have variance $\sim 1$ ?

Comment: As demonstrated by [Davide Giraudo in his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329646/limiting-distribution-of-frac1n-sum-k-1ns-k-1x-k2-1-where-x-k), the limiting distribution has the same law as the product $$ \left( 2\int_{0}^{1} W_s^2 \, \mathrm{d}s \right)^{1/2} N, $$ where $W=(W_s)_{s\geq 0}$ is the standard Brownian motion abd $N$ is a standard normal RV independent of $W$. Saying differently, the limiting distribution is $\mathcal{N}(0, 2\int_{0}^{1} W_s^2\,\mathrm{d}s)$.

Answer (score 2):

When I simulate the distribution then I get something that resembles a Laplace distribution. Even better seems to be a q-Gausian (the exact parameters you would have to find using theory).

I guess that your book must contain some variation of the CLT that relates to that (q-generalised central limit theorem, probably it is in Section 7.6 *The central limit theorem for sums of dependent variables*, but I can't look it up as I do not have the book available).

[image: simulation]

```r
library(qGaussian)
set.seed(1)
Qstore <- c(0) # vector to store result

n <- 10^6  # columns X_i
m <- 10^2  # rows repetitions

pb <- txtProgressBar(title = "progress bar", min = 0,
                     max = 100, style=3)
for (i in 1:100) {  
  # doing this several times because this matrix method takes a lot of memory
  # with smaller numbers n*m it can be done at once

  X <- matrix(rnorm(n*m,0,1),m)
  S <- t(sapply(1:m, FUN = function(x) cumsum(X[x,])))
  S <- cbind(rep(0,m),S[,-n])
  R <- abs(S)*(X^2-1)
  Q <- t(sapply(1:m, FUN = function(x) cumsum(R[x,])))

  Qstore <- c(Qstore,t(Q[,n]))
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
close(pb)

# compute histogram 
x <- seq(floor(min(Qstore/n)), ceiling(max(Qstore/n)), 0.2)
h <- hist(Qstore/(n),breaks = x)

# plot simulation
plot( h$mid, h$density, log = "y", xlim=c(-7,7),
      ylab = "log density" , xlab = expression(over(1,n)*sum(abs(S[k-1])*(X[k]^2-1),k==1,n) ) )

# distributions for comparison
lines(x, dnorm(x,0,1),                   col=1, lty=3)      #normal 
lines(x, dexp(abs(x),sqrt(2))/2,         col=1, lty=2)      #laplace
lines(x, qGaussian::dqgauss(x,sqrt(2),0,1/sqrt(2)), col=1, lty=1)      #qgauss

# further plotting
title("10^4 repetitions with n=10^6")
legend(-7,0.6,c("Gaussian", "Laplace", "Q-Gaussian"),col=1, lty=c(3,2,1),cex=0.8)
```

Comment: Regarding the content of the textbook, it's best that you see for yourself: [Volume 1](https://docdro.id/j1e2Nzr), [Volume 2](https://docdro.id/3lew9TE). The problem should only require material covered in Chapter 3.4

Comment: @GabrielRomon thank you very much for those links. Looking at it, from my phone, I could not find anything about the q-Gaussian or other limiting distributions that are not a normal distribution. So either the distribution has a very slow convergence n>>10^6 before we *see* it, or the question  doesn't fit the chapter (is it from the book, I could neither find the question?). A plot of the higher order moments (as function of n) might show better whether conversion might still happen, but I guess that this is not a typical CLT case.

Comment: This is Problem 3.4.14 in [the problem book](https://docdro.id/RfQunnN).